# How to share photo to Facebook within iOS app, when Facebook app is not installed on the phone?

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, swift3, facebook-share

Im using `FBSDKShareKit` (4.22.1), i'm trying to share photo with the following code:

```
let photo = FBSDKSharePhoto()
photo1.imageURL = URL(string: "sample url")
photo.isUserGenerated = false  
let photoContent = FBSDKSharePhotoContent()
photoContent.photos = [photo]
FBSDKShareDialog.show(from: self, with: photoContent, delegate: nil)
```

but it only works when the native Facebook app is installed on the phone.
I also tried to show the content with **Share Button** instead of **Share Dialog** like:

```
var shareButton = FBSDKShareButton()
shareButton.shareContent = photoContent
shareButton.center = self.view.center
self.view.addSubview(shareButton)
```

it didn't work, if app was not installed either.

i want the FBSDK i used in my app, opens Safari when Facebook app is not installed, it opens safari by default for **`FBSDKShareLinkContent`**, but not working for **`FBSDKSharePhotoContent`**.
does anyone know what is the problem?

Answer (score 2):

I have implemented another way to share photos using **Graph API**. It was very helpful. Here is [a link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/photo-uploads).
Just what you need is to take the permissions from the user to **publish_actions**
before posting.
Also there is no native facebook app installed. Just got logged in through Browser.

Comment: Yes, you are right. but i use login with read permission like: ```loginManager.logIn(withReadPermissions: ["email"], from: self)```, i can't use both read permission and publish permission, do you have any idea?

Comment: @Mina I have done this code 
`if((FBSDKAccessToken.current()) != nil){
  FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields":  "accounts,email"]).start(completionHandler: { (connection, result, error) -> Void in
                if (error == nil){
print(result)
    
                }
            })
        }` 
and I was able to access the email Id, I don't know whether this is proper solution

Answer (score 1):

Well, I found the answer in [Facebook developer website](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/ios), which is:

> Photos
>
> People can share photos from your app to Facebook with the Share
>   Dialog or with a custom interface:
>
> Photos must be less than 12MB in size
>
> People need the native Facebook for iOS app installed, version 7.0 or higher

you can also ask for "publish_actions", you need to login twice, first with readPermission for email, then when user wants to share a post loginWithPublishPermission for "publish_actions". the point is that you have to add "publish_actions" first of all in your Facebook developer account.